# Adding DOIs in Google Scholar results

Tags: chrome, google-apps, research

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can add DOI for each document in the results lists in Google Scholar (except for documents that don't have a DOI).

Any license and price is fine.

Comment: were you able to find any methods to get the DOIs?

Comment: @Dinesh no~~~~~

Comment: See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/114259/147505 for thoughts on how to make such an extension.

Comment: Is there a reason why Google Scholar does not want to use DOI? These identifiers are so useful and are now the norm for about every scientific field.

Answer (score 0):

Crossref has a DOI lookup API but there is a yearly fee.  You could create an extension that takes the Scholar results, sends to the API and returns DOIs to the page.